# TLS certificate with private IP address

Tags: tls, ip, apache

I am trying to get an Apache server running over HTTPS on a local network with an IP address 192.168.*.*

And our requirement is to make this local server secure. (no outside network / internet connection available)

I have gone through many tutorials / questions / forums / blogs and come to know that it is not possible to provide a self-signed certificate to a private address without the browser showing a warning.

As a last option I tried [to create my own CA](https://perfecto25.medium.com/getting-firefox-chrome-to-trust-your-internal-websites-internal-certificate-authority-a53ba2d4c2af) and it looks promising to me.

Does the above-mentioned process offer enough security to my local server?

Comment: This is not the right site to ask about server config troubleshooting.

Comment: I think my actual question got modified to a wrong question. this is not really my question.
Someone deleted my 2nd question.

Comment: That's what I said, we are not the right site to ask about server configurations, so I removed it. Leaving your first question, which I did not alter, This is still the question you wrote.